# Why is my Laravel Rest API sending verification link to email but redirecting to /login upon click?

Tags: laravel

I have created a laravel 10 project to build a Rest API.

After signing up as a user, a verification link is sent to the user's email. Unfortunately, clicking the verification link redirects to `/login,` which should not.

Here I create the user; after creating the user, I assign him an access token, and before that, I dispatch the Registered event (which sends a verification link to a user)

```
Route::post('/sign-up', function(Request $request){
    $user_created[] = $user;

    event(new Registered($user));

    $token = $user_created[0]->createToken($user_created[0]->email,['abilities:read-sellers,buy-products']);

    return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken, 'must_verify_email' => true];
});`
```

This endpoint verifies the user's email, but it is not working. Instead, the app redirects to /login, and the verification never happens.

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();
 
    return [
        "email_verified" => true
    ];

})->middleware(['signed'])->name('verification.verify');`
```

The API will be consumed from a mobile app, not a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Laravel as a REST API backend for a mobile app, the above mechanism might not be desirable or feasible. What you want instead is a route that just verifies the user and gives a suitable response without any redirects.

To handle this, you may override the default email verification mechanism and create your own.

First, ensure your user model uses the `MustVerifyEmail` interface.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    ...
}
```

Then, when a user registers, instead of triggering Laravel's registered event, create a unique verification token for each user and send that to the user via email.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$user->verification_token = Str::random(32);  // Or any other secure random string generation method you prefer
$user->save();
```

Then you create a new endpoint for verifying the email.

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{token}', function ($token) {
    $user = User::where('verification_token', $token)->first();
    if (!$user) {
    } else {
        $user->email_verified_at = now();
        $user->verification_token = null;
        $user->save();
        
        return [
            "email_verified" => true
        ];
    }
})->name('verification.verify');
```

This should bypass the redirection problem you're facing while providing a secure email verification feature.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).